# Is there any other sensors in android beside those?

Tags: android-sensors

so far, i've found below sensors in android devices. I'm going to develop an app putting information about all sensors available in device. For that i need to know how many sensors an android device can have beside those are given in below?

- Gyroscope Sensor
- Light Sensor
- Orientation Sensor
- Proximity Sensor
- Temperature Sensor
- Accelerometer Sensor
- Sound
- Magnetic Field
- Pressure

Any reference link, helpful comment will be appreciated.

Comment: The whitepaper for Sony Z3+, announced a couple of days ago, lists the impressive set of sensors in the new device. See the document here: http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/whitepapers/xperia-z3-e6553-white-paper/ . BTW the device is great (I have Z3 and plan to upgrade).

Answer (score 3):

When there is no gyroscope on the device, and only when there is no gyroscope, you may implement the rotation vector, linear acceleration and gravity sensors without using the gyroscope.
[image]

https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-types.html

Answer (score 1):

Barometer sensor - basically pressure for weather forecast, 
Step detecting sensor
and some orientation sensors with maximum 6-axis compared to the traditional 3-axis ones

Answer (score 1):

According to Google site there is total 13 sensors:

1. **ACCELEROMETER :** Measures the acceleration force
2. **AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE :** Measures the ambient room temperature
3. **GRAVITY :** Measures the force of gravity
4. **GYROSCOPE :** Measures a device's rate of rotation in rad/s around each of the three physical axes (x, y, and z).
5. **LIGHT :** Measures the ambient light level
6. **LINEAR_ACCELERATION :** Measures the acceleration force
7. **MAGNETIC_FIELD :** Measures the ambient geomagnetic field
8. **ORIENTATION :** Determining device position.
9. **PRESSURE :** Monitoring air pressure changes.
10. **PROXIMITY :** Phone position during a call.
11. **RELATIVE HUMIDITY :** Measures the relative ambient humidity in percent (%).
12. **ROTATION_VECTOR :** Motion detection and rotation detection.
13. **TEMPERATURE :** Monitoring temperatures.

For More information visit :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html